# setting page title when using strongly typed view data in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, strongly-typed-view

How can I set the page title in asp.net mvc using strongly typed views AND a master page.

**I added a public property to my master page class, but can't seem to get access to it in my view/action.**

Answer (score 5):

Setup a placeholder in the head of your master page:

```
<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
```

Then in your view pages add an asp:Content section:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    <%= Model.Title %>
</asp:Content>
```